# How to merge CSV files in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to the Hadoop framework and I would like to merge 4 CSV files into a single file.

All the 4 CSV files have same headers and order is also the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Pig `STORE` offers such a feature.

You could use Spark's `coalesce(1)` function, however, there is little reason to do this as almost all Hadoop processing tools prefer to read directories, not files.

You should ideally not be storing raw CSV in Hadoop for very long, anyway, and rather you convert it to ORC or Parquet as columnar data. Especially if you are reading CSV to begin with already -- do not output CSV again.

---

If the idea is to produce one CSV to later download, then I would suggest using Hive + Beeline to do that

This will store the result into a file in the **local file system**.

```
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://[databaseaddress]' --outputformat=csv2 -f yourSQlFile.sql > theFileWhereToStoreTheData.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

try using getmerge utility to merge the csv files 
for example you have a couple of EMP_FILE1.csv EMP_FILE2.csv EMP_FILE3.csv are placed at some location on hdfs. you can merge all these files and can placed merge file at some new location.

hadoop fs -getmerge /hdfsfilelocation/EMP_FILE* /newhdfsfilelocation/MERGED_EMP_FILE.csv